# How to Auto scroll specific div without using jquery?

Tags: html

In HTML, how to Auto scroll specific div without using jquery? I want to scroll only specific div or textarea to autoscroll on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a ID anchor in your page like:

```
<span id="scrollHere"></span>
```

Then on page load you can call some javascript to auto scroll to that point:

```
location.href = "#scrollHere";
```

This wont animate the scroll but it will do what you need.

In an attempt to fully answer your question, if you want to scroll a textarea (presuming you mean a  and not just a paragraph of text. you will need to use Js for this also, you can use:

```
scrollTo();
```

or

```
scrollBy(dx,dy);
```

to scroll an element. An example would be:

```
document.getElementById('textareaID').scrollBy(0, 50);
```